# Is it possible to develop a new custom checkout page as same as default Checkout page in magento

Tags: magento-1.7

> I  am trying to make a new checkout page exactly same as default
>   checkout page, is it possible to do default checkout page to a custom
>   checkout page, what are the initial steps to achieve that.

Comment: What on earth is the point of building another one page checkout that's exactly the same as the existing one? Are you just talking about restyling it?

Comment: What you want to do would certainly be possible, although the steps needed to do it would long, tedious, and error prone.  You'd need to copy everything in the Mage_Checkout module, as well as all the templates it renders, as well as its layout xml update file, change the frontname to a new frontname, and change all URL references to use the new frontname, change all the template references to use the new template names, and probably 5 other things I forgot.  Whatever time you're trying to save by doing this would be better spent finding a different approach.

Comment: I cannot fathom why you would want to do this. Maybe you can explain your end goal, as just duplicating the current checkout makes no sense.

Comment: actually i need the default checkout page and the new custom checkout page(same as default and i need to do some customisation in the design) but right now i am new in magento so it is very hard to develop a custom checkout page same as default checkout page options any possible solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

Just copy the template/checkout folder into your own theme.

If your checkout folder is in app/design/base/default/frontend/tempalate/checkout then copy that into app/design/default/yourcustomtheme/checkout and set your design to that theme. Then you can do whatever you want to onepage or the cart page, whatever you want.

Comment: Is it possible to switch the default checkout to custom checkout and vice versa from the magento admin panel

Comment: Is this path correct app/design/default/yourcustomtheme/checkout ? then how it will redirect to the custom theme checkout?